# Updating Parent table when Child table is updated

Tags: javascript, html, r, shiny, dt

I have a nested table in my Shiny app. The child table allows the user to go in and manually edit the values in a few columns (`Share (%)`, `Spot:30(%)`, and `Spot:15(%)`). When those values are updated the totals row will update and the columns `Gross CPP($)` and `Gross CPM($)` will also update.

In the `parent` table when the `child` values are updated the `parent` `Gross CPP($)` and `Gross CPM($)` should also update. The `parent` table `Gross CPP($)` and `Gross CPM($)` are a weighted average of the `child` table `Gross CPP($)` and `Gross CPM($)`, where the weight is the `Share (%)`.

My issue here is that I can't seem to figure out how to make the this happen. Do I need to have this happen on the `JavaScript` callback side of things or in the `R` server side of things?

**Parent & Child Table**
[image]

Child table data:

```
structure(list(Daypart = c("Daytime", "Early Fringe", "Early Morning", 
"Early News", "Late Fringe", "Late News", "Prime Access", "Prime Time"
), `Share (%)` = c(15, 15, 15, 15, 10, 10, 10, 10), `Spot:30 (%)` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `Spot:15 (%)` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0), `Gross CPM` = c("$0", "$0", "$0", "$0", "$0", "$0", "$0", 
"$0")), .Names = c("Daypart", "Share (%)", "Spot:30 (%)", "Spot:15 (%)", 
"Gross CPM"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Parent table data:

```
structure(list(Market = c("ABILENE-SWEETWATER", "ALBANY-SCHENECTADY-TROY, NY"
), `Gross CPP` = c("$0", "$0"), `Gross CPM` = c("$0", "$0"), 
    `Historical Composite Gross CPP (if applicable)` = c("$0", 
    "$0"), `Historical Composite Gross CPM (if applicable)` = c("$0", 
    "$0")), .Names = c("Market", "Gross CPP", "Gross CPM", "Historical Composite Gross CPP (if applicable)", 
"Historical Composite Gross CPM (if applicable)"), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = "data.frame")
```

**Code**

```
# The callback to format the datatable
parentRows <- which(Dat[,1] != "")
callback_js = JS(
  "function onUpdate(updatedCell, updatedRow, oldValue) {};",
  sprintf("var parentRows = [%s];", toString(parentRows-1)),
  sprintf("var j0 = %d;", colIdx),
  "var nrows = table.rows().count();",
  "for(var i=0; i < nrows; ++i){",
  "  if(parentRows.indexOf(i) > -1){",
  "    table.cell(i,j0).nodes().to$().css({cursor: 'pointer'});",
  "  }else{",
  "    table.cell(i,j0).nodes().to$().removeClass('details-control');",
  "  }",
  "}",
  "",
  "// make the table header of the nested table",
  "var format = function(d, childId){",
  "  if(d != null){",
  "    var html = ", 
  "      '<table class=\"display compact hover\" ' + ",
  "      'style=\"padding-left: 30px;\" id=\"' + childId + '\"><thead><tr>';",
  "    for(var key in d[d.length-1][0]){",
  "      html += '<th>' + key + '</th>';",
  "    }",
  "    html += '</tr></thead><tfoot><tr>'",
  "    for(var key in d[d.length-1][0]){",
  "      html += '<th></th>';",
  "    }",
  "    return html + '</tr></tfoot></table>';",
  "  } else {",
  "    return '';",
  "  }",
  "};",
  "",
  "// row callback to style the rows of the child tables",
  "var rowCallback = function(row, dat, displayNum, index){",
  "  if($(row).hasClass('odd')){",
  "    $(row).css('background-color', 'white');",
  "    $(row).hover(function(){",
  "      $(this).css('background-color', 'lightgreen');",
  "    }, function() {",
  "      $(this).css('background-color', 'white');",
  "    });",
  "  } else {",
  "    $(row).css('background-color', 'white');",
  "    $(row).hover(function(){",
  "      $(this).css('background-color', 'lightblue');",
  "    }, function() {",
  "      $(this).css('background-color', 'white');",
  "    });",
  "  }",
  "};",
  "",
  "// header callback to style the header of the child tables",
  "var headerCallback = function(thead, data, start, end, display){",
  "  $('th', thead).css({",
  "    'border-top': '3px solid green',", 
  "    'color': 'black',",
  "    'background-color': 'white'",
  "  });",
  "};",
  "",
  "// footer callback to display the totals",
  "var footerCallback = function(tfoot, data, start, end, display){",
  "  $('th', tfoot).css('background-color', '#F4F1F1');",
  "  var api = this.api();",
  "  api.columns().eq(0).each(function(index){",
  "    if(index == 0) return $(api.column(index).footer()).html('Total');",
  "    var coldata = api.column(index).data();",
  "    var total = coldata", 
  "          .reduce(function(a, b){return parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b)}, 0);",
  "    $(api.column(index).footer()).html(total);",
  "  })",
  "}",
  "",
  "// make the datatable",
  "var format_datatable = function(d, childId){",
  "  var dataset = [];",
  "  var n = d.length - 1;",
  "  for(var i = 0; i < d[n].length; i++){",
  "    var datarow = $.map(d[n][i], function (value, index) {",
  "      return [value];",
  "    });",
  "    dataset.push(datarow);",
  "  }",
  "  var id = 'table#' + childId;",
  "  if (Object.keys(d[n][0]).indexOf('_details') === -1) {",
  "    var subtable = $(id).DataTable({",
  "                 'data': dataset,",
  "                 'autoWidth': true,",
  "                 'deferRender': true,",
  "                 'info': false,",
  "                 'lengthChange': false,",
  "                 'ordering': d[n].length > 1,",
  "                 'order': [],",
  "                 'paging': false,",
  "                 'scrollX': false,",
  "                 'scrollY': false,",
  "                 'searching': false,",
  "                 'sortClasses': false,",
  "                 'rowCallback': rowCallback,",
  "                 'headerCallback': headerCallback,",
  "                 'footerCallback': footerCallback,",
  "                 'columnDefs': [{targets: '_all', className: 'dt-center'}]",
  "               });",
  "  } else {",
  "    var subtable = $(id).DataTable({",
  "            'data': dataset,",
  "            'autoWidth': true,",
  "            'deferRender': true,",
  "            'info': false,",
  "            'lengthChange': false,",
  "            'ordering': d[n].length > 1,",
  "            'order': [],",
  "            'paging': false,",
  "            'scrollX': false,",
  "            'scrollY': false,",
  "            'searching': false,",
  "            'sortClasses': false,",
  "            'rowCallback': rowCallback,",
  "            'headerCallback': headerCallback,",
  "            'footerCallback': footerCallback,",
  "            'columnDefs': [", 
  "              {targets: -1, visible: false},", 
  "              {targets: 0, orderable: false, className: 'details-control'},", 
  "              {targets: '_all', className: 'dt-center'}",
  "             ]",
  "          }).column(0).nodes().to$().css({cursor: 'pointer'});",
  "  }",
  "  subtable.MakeCellsEditable({",
  "    onUpdate: onUpdate,",
  "    inputCss: 'my-input-class',",
  "    columns: [1,2,3],",
  "    confirmationButton: {",
  "      confirmCss: 'my-confirm-class',",
  "      cancelCss: 'my-cancel-class'",
  "    }",
  "  });",
  "};",
  "",
  "// display the child table on click",
  "table.on('click', 'td.details-control', function(){",
  "  var tbl = $(this).closest('table'),",
  "      tblId = tbl.attr('id'),",
  "      td = $(this),",
  "      row = $(tbl).DataTable().row(td.closest('tr')),",
  "      rowIdx = row.index();",
  "  if(row.child.isShown()){",
  "    row.child.hide();",
  "    td.html('&oplus;');",
  "  } else {",
  "    var childId = tblId + '-child-' + rowIdx;",
  "    row.child(format(row.data(), childId)).show();",
  "    td.html('&CircleMinus;');",
  "    format_datatable(row.data(), childId);",
  "  }",
  "});")

## Server.R
# Bind the market level and mix breakout data together for the final table
market_mix_table <- reactive({
  markets <- market_costings_gross_net()
  mix_breakout <- daypart_break_out()

  # Need to use replicate() on mix_breakout_table for cases when there is an arbitrary number of rows in markets 
  n <-  nrow(markets)
  children_list <- replicate(n, mix_breakout, simplify = FALSE)
  # Make the dataframe
  # This must be met length(children) == nrow(dat)
  Dat <- NestedData(
    dat = markets,
    children = children_list
  )
  return(Dat)
})
# Render the table
output$daypartTable <- DT::renderDataTable({
  # Whether to show row names (set TRUE or FALSE)
  rowNames <- FALSE
  colIdx <- as.integer(rowNames)
  # The data
  Dat <- market_mix_table()
  # Table
  table <- DT::datatable(
    Dat,
    callback = callback_js, 
    rownames = rowNames, 
    escape = -colIdx-1,
      options = list(
        columnDefs = list(
          list(visible = FALSE, targets = ncol(Dat)-1+colIdx),
          list(orderable = FALSE, className = 'details-control', targets = colIdx),
          list(className = "dt-center", targets = "_all")
        )
      )
    )
  # Some faancy Java magic
  path <- getwd()
  dep <- htmltools::htmlDependency(
    "CellEdit", "1.0.19", path, 
    script = "dataTables.cellEdit.js", stylesheet = "dataTables.cellEdit.css")
  table$dependencies <- c(table$dependencies, list(dep))
  return(table)
})
```

**EDIT**
After adding the new calculations to the `footer callback`, the table doesn't want to keep the child table open. Each time I click the `+` button to expand it the table shows just for a millisecond and then hides itself again.

```
## make the callback
parentRows <- which(Dat[,1] != "")
callback_js = JS(
  "function onUpdate(updatedCell, updatedRow, oldValue) {};",
  sprintf("var parentRows = [%s];", toString(parentRows-1)),
  sprintf("var j0 = %d;", colIdx),
  "var nrows = table.rows().count();",
  "for(var i=0; i < nrows; ++i){",
  "  if(parentRows.indexOf(i) > -1){",
  "    table.cell(i,j0).nodes().to$().css({cursor: 'pointer'});",
  "  }else{",
  "    table.cell(i,j0).nodes().to$().removeClass('details-control');",
  "  }",
  "}",
  "",
  "// make the table header of the nested table",
  "var format = function(d, childId){",
  "  if(d != null){",
  "    var html = ",
  "      '<table class=\"display compact hover\" ' + ",
  "      'style=\"padding-left: 30px;\" id=\"' + childId + '\"><thead><tr>';",
  "    for(var key in d[d.length-1][0]){",
  "      html += '<th>' + key + '</th>';",
  "    }",
  "    html += '</tr></thead><tfoot><tr>'",
  "    for(var key in d[d.length-1][0]){",
  "      html += '<th></th>';",
  "    }",
  "    return html + '</tr></tfoot></table>';",
  "  } else {",
  "    return '';",
  "  }",
  "};",
  "",
  "// row callback to style the rows of the child tables",
  "var rowCallback = function(row, dat, displayNum, index){",
  "  if($(row).hasClass('odd')){",
  "    $(row).css('background-color', 'white');",
  "    $(row).hover(function(){",
  "      $(this).css('background-color', 'lightgreen');",
  "    }, function() {",
  "      $(this).css('background-color', 'white');",
  "    });",
  "  } else {",
  "    $(row).css('background-color', 'white');",
  "    $(row).hover(function(){",
  "      $(this).css('background-color', 'lightblue');",
  "    }, function() {",
  "      $(this).css('background-color', 'white');",
  "    });",
  "  }",
  "};",
  "",
  "// header callback to style the header of the child tables",
  "var headerCallback = function(thead, data, start, end, display){",
  "  $('th', thead).css({",
  "    'border-top': '3px solid green',",
  "    'color': 'black',",
  "    'background-color': 'white'",
  "  });",
  "};",
  "",
  "// make the datatable",
  "var format_datatable = function(d, childId, rowIdx){",
  "  // footer callback to display the totals",
  "  // and update the parent row",
  "  var footerCallback = function(tfoot, data, start, end, display){",
  "    $('th', tfoot).css('background-color', '#fed8b1');",
  "    var api = this.api();",
  "    api.columns().eq(0).each(function(index){",
  "      if(index == 0) return $(api.column(index).footer()).html('Total');",
  "      var coldata = api.column(index).data();",
  "      var total = coldata",
  "          .reduce(function(a, b){return parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b)}, 0);",
  "      $(api.column(index).footer()).html(total);",
  "    })",
  "    var col_share = api.column(1).data();",
  "    var col_CPP = api.column(4).data();",
  "    var col_CPM = api.column(5).data();",
  "    var CPP = 0, CPM = 0;",
  "    for(var i = 0; i < col_share.length; i++){",
  "      CPP += parseFloat(col_share[i])*parseFloat(col_CPP[i]);",
  "      CPM += parseFloat(col_share[i])*parseFloat(col_CPM[i]);",
  "    }",
  "    table.cell(rowIdx, j0+2).data('$' + (CPP/100));",
  "    table.cell(rowIdx, j0+3).data('$' + (CPM/100)).draw();",
  "  }",
  "  var dataset = [];",
  "  var n = d.length - 1;",
  "  for(var i = 0; i < d[n].length; i++){",
  "    var datarow = $.map(d[n][i], function (value, index) {",
  "      return [value];",
  "    });",
  "    dataset.push(datarow);",
  "  }",
  "  var id = 'table#' + childId;",
  "  if (Object.keys(d[n][0]).indexOf('_details') === -1) {",
  "    var subtable = $(id).DataTable({",
  "                 'data': dataset,",
  "                 'autoWidth': true,",
  "                 'deferRender': true,",
  "                 'info': false,",
  "                 'lengthChange': false,",
  "                 'ordering': d[n].length > 1,",
  "                 'order': [],",
  "                 'paging': false,",
  "                 'scrollX': false,",
  "                 'scrollY': false,",
  "                 'searching': false,",
  "                 'sortClasses': false,",
  "                 'rowCallback': rowCallback,",
  "                 'headerCallback': headerCallback,",
  "                 'footerCallback': footerCallback,",
  "                 'columnDefs': [{targets: '_all', className: 'dt-center'}]",
  "               });",
  "  } else {",
  "    var subtable = $(id).DataTable({",
  "            'data': dataset,",
  "            'autoWidth': true,",
  "            'deferRender': true,",
  "            'info': false,",
  "            'lengthChange': false,",
  "            'ordering': d[n].length > 1,",
  "            'order': [],",
  "            'paging': false,",
  "            'scrollX': false,",
  "            'scrollY': false,",
  "            'searching': false,",
  "            'sortClasses': false,",
  "            'rowCallback': rowCallback,",
  "            'headerCallback': headerCallback,",
  "            'footerCallback': footerCallback,",
  "            'columnDefs': [",
  "              {targets: -1, visible: false},",
  "              {targets: 0, orderable: false, className: 'details-control'},",
  "              {targets: '_all', className: 'dt-center'}",
  "             ]",
  "          }).column(0).nodes().to$().css({cursor: 'pointer'});",
  "  }",
  "  subtable.MakeCellsEditable({",
  "    onUpdate: onUpdate,",
  "    inputCss: 'my-input-class',",
  "    confirmationButton: {",
  "      confirmCss: 'my-confirm-class',",
  "      cancelCss: 'my-cancel-class'",
  "    }",
  "  });",
  "};",
  "",
  "// display the child table on click",
  "table.on('click', 'td.details-control', function(){",
  "  var tbl = $(this).closest('table'),",
  "      tblId = tbl.attr('id'),",
  "      td = $(this),",
  "      row = $(tbl).DataTable().row(td.closest('tr')),",
  "      rowIdx = row.index();",
  "  if(row.child.isShown()){",
  "    row.child.hide();",
  "    td.html('&oplus;');",
  "  } else {",
  "    var childId = tblId + '-child-' + rowIdx;",
  "    row.child(format(row.data(), childId)).show();",
  "    td.html('&CircleMinus;');",
  "    format_datatable(row.data(), childId, rowIdx);",
  "  }",
  "});")

# Module to create the nested structure of the table
NestedData <- function(dat, children){
  stopifnot(length(children) == nrow(dat))
  g <- function(d){
    if(is.data.frame(d)){
      purrr::transpose(d)
    }else{
      purrr::transpose(NestedData(d[[1]], children = d$children))
    }
  }
  subdats <- lapply(children, g)
  oplus <- sapply(subdats, function(x) if(length(x)) "&oplus;" else "")
  cbind(" " = oplus, dat, "_details" = I(subdats), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}
# Bind the market level and mix breakout data together for the final table
market_mix_table <- reactive({

  # Need to use replicate() on mix_breakout_table for cases when there is an arbitrary number of rows in markets 
  n <-  nrow(parent_df)
  children_list <- replicate(n, child_df, simplify = FALSE)
  # Make the dataframe
  # This must be met length(children) == nrow(dat)
  Dat <- NestedData(
    dat = parent_df,
    children = children_list
  )
  return(Dat)
})
# Render the table
output$daypartTable <- DT::renderDataTable({
  # Whether to show row names (set TRUE or FALSE)
  rowNames <- FALSE
  colIdx <- as.integer(rowNames)
  # The data
  Dat <- market_mix_table()
  # Table
  table <- DT::datatable(
    Dat,
    callback = callback_js,
    rownames = rowNames,
    escape = -colIdx-1,
      options = list(
        columnDefs = list(
          list(visible = FALSE, targets = ncol(Dat)-1+colIdx),
          list(orderable = FALSE, className = 'details-control', targets = colIdx),
          list(className = "dt-center", targets = "_all")
        )
      )
    )
  # Some faancy Java magic
  path <- getwd()
  dep <- htmltools::htmlDependency(
    "CellEdit", "1.0.19", path,
    script = "dataTables.cellEdit.js", stylesheet = "dataTables.cellEdit.css")
  table$dependencies <- c(table$dependencies, list(dep))
  return(table)
})
```

Comment: What is the formula exactly? `GrossCPP(parent) = TotalShare/100 * TotalGrossCPP(child) + (1 - TotalShare/100) * TotalGrossCPM(child)`?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent , My apologies for not being clear on the formula. There are two formulas; one for `Gross CPP (parent)` and one for `Gross CPM (parent)`. `Gross CPP(parent) = Σ(daypart share/100) * Gross CPP (child)`. `Gross CPM(parent) = Σ(daypart share/100) * Gross CPM (child)`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds good. I put the calculations in the footer callback.

```
df_child <- structure(
  list(
    Daypart = c("Daytime", "Early Fringe", "Early Morning", "Early News", "Late Fringe", "Late News", "Prime Access", "Prime Time"), 
    `Share (%)` = c(15, 15, 15, 15, 10, 10, 10, 10), 
    `Spot:30 (%)` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    `Spot:15 (%)` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    `Gross CPP ($)` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    `Gross CPM ($)` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
  ), 
  .Names = c("Daypart", "Share (%)", "Spot:30 (%)", "Spot:15 (%)", "Gross CPP ($)", "Gross CPM ($)"), 
  row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")

df_parent <- structure(
  list(
    Market = c("ABILENE-SWEETWATER", "ALBANY-SCHENECTADY-TROY, NY"), 
    `Gross CPP` = c("$0", "$0"), 
    `Gross CPM` = c("$0", "$0"), 
    `Historical Composite Gross CPP (if applicable)` = c("$0", "$0"), 
    `Historical Composite Gross CPM (if applicable)` = c("$0", "$0")), 
  .Names = c("Market", "Gross CPP", "Gross CPM", "Historical Composite Gross CPP (if applicable)", "Historical Composite Gross CPM (if applicable)"), 
  row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")

# function to make the required dataframe
NestedData <- function(dat, children){
  stopifnot(length(children) == nrow(dat))
  g <- function(d){
    if(is.data.frame(d)){
      purrr::transpose(d)
    }else{
      purrr::transpose(NestedData(d[[1]], children = d$children))
    }
  }
  subdats <- lapply(children, g)
  oplus <- sapply(subdats, function(x) if(length(x)) "&oplus;" else "")
  cbind(" " = oplus, dat, "_details" = I(subdats), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}

# make the required dataframe
# one must have: length(children) == nrow(dat)
Dat <- NestedData(
  dat = df_parent, 
  children = list(df_child, df_child)
)

## whether to show row names (set TRUE or FALSE)
rowNames <- FALSE
colIdx <- as.integer(rowNames)

## make the callback
parentRows <- which(Dat[,1] != "")
callback = JS(
  "function onUpdate(updatedCell, updatedRow, oldValue) {};",
  "table.MakeCellsEditable({",
  "  onUpdate: onUpdate,",
  "  inputCss: 'my-input-class',",
  "  confirmationButton: {",
  "    confirmCss: 'my-confirm-class',",
  "    cancelCss: 'my-cancel-class'",
  "  }",
  "});",
  sprintf("var parentRows = [%s];", toString(parentRows-1)),
  sprintf("var j0 = %d;", colIdx),
  "var nrows = table.rows().count();",
  "for(var i=0; i < nrows; ++i){",
  "  if(parentRows.indexOf(i) > -1){",
  "    table.cell(i,j0).nodes().to$().css({cursor: 'pointer'});",
  "  }else{",
  "    table.cell(i,j0).nodes().to$().removeClass('details-control');",
  "  }",
  "}",
  "",
  "// make the table header of the nested table",
  "var format = function(d, childId){",
  "  if(d != null){",
  "    var html = ", 
  "      '<table class=\"display compact hover\" ' + ",
  "      'style=\"padding-left: 30px;\" id=\"' + childId + '\"><thead><tr>';",
  "    for(var key in d[d.length-1][0]){",
  "      html += '<th>' + key + '</th>';",
  "    }",
  "    html += '</tr></thead><tfoot><tr>'",
  "    for(var key in d[d.length-1][0]){",
  "      html += '<th></th>';",
  "    }",
  "    return html + '</tr></tfoot></table>';",
  "  } else {",
  "    return '';",
  "  }",
  "};",
  "",
  "// row callback to style the rows of the child tables",
  "var rowCallback = function(row, dat, displayNum, index){",
  "  if($(row).hasClass('odd')){",
  "    $(row).css('background-color', 'papayawhip');",
  "    $(row).hover(function(){",
  "      $(this).css('background-color', '#E6FF99');",
  "    }, function() {",
  "      $(this).css('background-color', 'papayawhip');",
  "    });",
  "  } else {",
  "    $(row).css('background-color', 'lemonchiffon');",
  "    $(row).hover(function(){",
  "      $(this).css('background-color', '#DDFF75');",
  "    }, function() {",
  "      $(this).css('background-color', 'lemonchiffon');",
  "    });",
  "  }",
  "};",
  "",
  "// header callback to style the header of the child tables",
  "var headerCallback = function(thead, data, start, end, display){",
  "  $('th', thead).css({",
  "    'border-top': '3px solid indigo',", 
  "    'color': 'indigo',",
  "    'background-color': '#fadadd'",
  "  });",
  "};",
  "",
  "// make the datatable",
  "var format_datatable = function(d, childId, rowIdx){",
  "  // footer callback to display the totals",
  "  // and update the parent row",
  "  var footerCallback = function(tfoot, data, start, end, display){",
  "    $('th', tfoot).css('background-color', '#fed8b1');",
  "    var api = this.api();",
  "    api.columns().eq(0).each(function(index){",
  "      if(index == 0) return $(api.column(index).footer()).html('Total');",
  "      var coldata = api.column(index).data();",
  "      var total = coldata", 
  "          .reduce(function(a, b){return parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b)}, 0);",
  "      $(api.column(index).footer()).html(total);",
  "    })",
  "    var col_share = api.column(1).data();",
  "    var col_CPP = api.column(4).data();",
  "    var col_CPM = api.column(5).data();",
  "    var CPP = 0, CPM = 0;",
  "    for(var i = 0; i < col_share.length; i++){",
  "      CPP += parseFloat(col_share[i])*parseFloat(col_CPP[i]);",
  "      CPM += parseFloat(col_share[i])*parseFloat(col_CPM[i]);",
  "    }",
  "    table.cell(rowIdx, j0+2).data('$' + (CPP/100));",
  "    table.cell(rowIdx, j0+3).data('$' + (CPM/100)).draw();",
  "  }",
  "  var dataset = [];",
  "  var n = d.length - 1;",
  "  for(var i = 0; i < d[n].length; i++){",
  "    var datarow = $.map(d[n][i], function (value, index) {",
  "      return [value];",
  "    });",
  "    dataset.push(datarow);",
  "  }",
  "  var id = 'table#' + childId;",
  "  if (Object.keys(d[n][0]).indexOf('_details') === -1) {",
  "    var subtable = $(id).DataTable({",
  "                 'data': dataset,",
  "                 'autoWidth': true,",
  "                 'deferRender': true,",
  "                 'info': false,",
  "                 'lengthChange': false,",
  "                 'ordering': d[n].length > 1,",
  "                 'order': [],",
  "                 'paging': false,",
  "                 'scrollX': false,",
  "                 'scrollY': false,",
  "                 'searching': false,",
  "                 'sortClasses': false,",
  "                 'rowCallback': rowCallback,",
  "                 'headerCallback': headerCallback,",
  "                 'footerCallback': footerCallback,",
  "                 'columnDefs': [{targets: '_all', className: 'dt-center'}]",
  "               });",
  "  } else {",
  "    var subtable = $(id).DataTable({",
  "            'data': dataset,",
  "            'autoWidth': true,",
  "            'deferRender': true,",
  "            'info': false,",
  "            'lengthChange': false,",
  "            'ordering': d[n].length > 1,",
  "            'order': [],",
  "            'paging': false,",
  "            'scrollX': false,",
  "            'scrollY': false,",
  "            'searching': false,",
  "            'sortClasses': false,",
  "            'rowCallback': rowCallback,",
  "            'headerCallback': headerCallback,",
  "            'footerCallback': footerCallback,",
  "            'columnDefs': [", 
  "              {targets: -1, visible: false},", 
  "              {targets: 0, orderable: false, className: 'details-control'},", 
  "              {targets: '_all', className: 'dt-center'}",
  "             ]",
  "          }).column(0).nodes().to$().css({cursor: 'pointer'});",
  "  }",
  "  subtable.MakeCellsEditable({",
  "    onUpdate: onUpdate,",
  "    inputCss: 'my-input-class',",
  "    confirmationButton: {",
  "      confirmCss: 'my-confirm-class',",
  "      cancelCss: 'my-cancel-class'",
  "    }",
  "  });",
  "};",
  "",
  "// display the child table on click",
  "table.on('click', 'td.details-control', function(){",
  "  var tbl = $(this).closest('table'),",
  "      tblId = tbl.attr('id'),",
  "      td = $(this),",
  "      row = $(tbl).DataTable().row(td.closest('tr')),",
  "      rowIdx = row.index();",
  "  if(row.child.isShown()){",
  "    row.child.hide();",
  "    td.html('&oplus;');",
  "  } else {",
  "    var childId = tblId + '-child-' + rowIdx;",
  "    row.child(format(row.data(), childId)).show();",
  "    td.html('&CircleMinus;');",
  "    format_datatable(row.data(), childId, rowIdx);",
  "  }",
  "});")

## the datatable
dtable <- datatable(
  Dat, callback = callback, rownames = rowNames, escape = -colIdx-1,
  options = list(
    columnDefs = list(
      list(visible = FALSE, targets = ncol(Dat)-1+colIdx),
      list(orderable = FALSE, className = 'details-control', targets = colIdx),
      list(className = "dt-center", targets = "_all")
    )
  )
)
path <- "~/Work/R/DT" # folder containing the files dataTables.cellEdit.js
                      # and dataTables.cellEdit.css
dep <- htmltools::htmlDependency(
  "CellEdit", "1.0.19", path, 
  script = "dataTables.cellEdit.js", stylesheet = "dataTables.cellEdit.css")
dtable$dependencies <- c(dtable$dependencies, list(dep))
dtable
```

Comment: I tried your solution and when I go to expend the child table it briefly shows but then quickly hides itself without me hitting the `-` button to hide it.

Comment: @TimothyMcwilliams Have you copied-pasted my code (and changed the `path` variable)? Without change? For me it works.

Comment: The only code I copied was the `callback` block. I wonder why that isn't working on my side

Comment: I've isolated it down to where the new calculations are, all I did was comment out that new block and the child table stayed put. is it an indentation issue you think?

Comment: @TimothyMcwilliams No, the indentation has no effect. Does it work if you copy all my code ?

Comment: Nope, I copied everything but where you create your `dataframes` and it keeps doing the same thing. Child table pops open for like a millisecond and then hides itself